# why nl2br many <br>

Tags: php, bbcode, nl2br

I create a bbcode parser
I used nl2br() when output.
But, why will be this result

input

```
[table][tr][td]1[/td]
[td]2[/td]
[/tr]
[tr][td]3[/td]
[td]4[/td]
[/tr]
[/table]

[ul]
[li]1[/li]
[li]2[/li]
[li]3[/li]
[/ul]

[ol]
[li]A[/li]
[li]B[/li]
[li]C[/li]
[/ol]
```

output

```
<br><br><br><br><br><br><table><tbody><tr><td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table><br>
<br>
<ul><br>
<li>1</li><br>
<li>2</li><br>
<li>3</li><br>
</ul><br>
<br>
<ol><br>
<li>A</li><br>
<li>B</li><br>
<li>C</li><br>
</ol><br>
```

my php function

```
function showBBcodes($text) {

     $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
     preg_match_all('#\[code\](.*?)\[/code]#is', $text, $stack);  

    // BBcode array
    $find = array(
        '~\[ul\](.*?)\[/ul\]~s',
        '~\[li\](.*?)\[/li\]~s',
        '~\[ol\](.*?)\[/ol\]~s',
        '~\[table\](.*?)\[/table\]~s',
        '~\[tr\](.*?)\[/tr\]~s',
        '~\[td\](.*?)\[/td\]~s',
        '~\[img\](.*?)\[/img\]~s',
        '/\[img=(\d+)x(\d+)\](.*?)\[\/img\]/is'
    );

    // HTML tags to replace BBcode
    $replace = array(
        '<ul>$1</ul>',
        '<li>$1</li>',
        '<ol>$1</ol>',
        '<table>$1</table>',
        '<tr>$1</tr>',
        '<td>$1</td>',
        '<img src="$1" alt=""/>',
        '<img width="$1" height="$2" src="$3" alt="" />'
    );       
    $text = preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
    $text = nl2br($text);

    foreach($stack[1] as $t) {
      $text = preg_replace('#\[code\].*?\[/code]#is','<div class="code_box">'.$t.'</div>', $text,1); 
    }
    return $text;
}
```

My test:
Between [ table ] and [/ table], show six times \n.
so Before [table] appeared six times

how can I fixed that?

can I skip not use nl2br in [table] [ul] [li]  but use in [tr]  [li]??

or anyone can give me more suggest

thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why but you can use ltrim to get rid of the whitespace before the table output. `$text = ltrim($text);`

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But I test used 
         $text = ltrim($text); before the table output. still show 6 times <br> :(

Comment: It's because showBBcodes() is not adding any whitespace before. It's a browser thing, its moving all the brs outside the table markup.

Comment: I think that not browser thing. because if not start from [table]... it will be normal

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer : [nl2br() in textarea with BBCode and HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092418/nl2br-in-textarea-with-bbcode-and-html-code)

```
$formattedText = preg_replace("/(<[a-zA-Z0-9=\"\/\ ]+>)<br\ \/>/", "$1", nl2br($text));
```

Comment: To be honest, I would rather not do nl2br to all of its content. There's no need to add them to <tds> or <trs> or <li> because those will format the text accordingly. What you can do is just replace the empty lines with <br>.

Comment: thank your comment. But my project is a little forum. you suggest your plan better nl2br? I will consider your proposal

Answer (score 0):

Use nl2br for content of tags li and td only

For example:

```
preg_match_all('#\[li\](.*?)\[/li]#is', $text, $stack);
foreach($stack[1] as $t) {
  $text = str_replace($t, nl2br($t), $text); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks your reply. But other I need nl2br. all content need nl2br. just want to fix appeared six times before [table]. and Between [ul] and [/ul]